# SQL not saving values ò,à,ù,è

Tags: php, mysql, sql, character, special-characters

I have users inserting comments for their courses, and I save them on SQL like this:

```
$return = $_POST;
$x = $return["comment1"];

$result = "UPDATE  Students SET  `Comment1` =  '$x' WHERE  StudEmail = '$email'  ";
```

My question is the following: since they are italian, they use letters like: ò,à,ù,è. When SQL saves them, it doesn't recognise them. And obviously, when I print out those comments, it will print them out with a weird symbol.

Any advice?

Example:
Comment: Mi è piaciuto
SQL saves: Mi ï¿½ piaciuto

Comment: And please, please, please learn to use prepared statements/bind variables before SQL injection strikes, or you have a comment containing an apostrophe (whichever is sooner)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to search for those chars and replace them with the appropriate ascii value.

This link should help you find the values

> http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

For example:

Letter `è` equals to `&#232;`

Hope this helps.